# Is there a way to group records by position range in input?

Tags: xquery, basex

Is there any way to group input by position range? 
In my case i have a function that consumes multiple strings. I need to group them by static position range (1-3, 4-6, 7-9 etc.) an then execute some code for each of this group in for loop. 
I dont know how many strings is passed. It can change depending on input.

I have tried iterate with for $x at $i in... but couldnt get it right

```
 declare function bs:concat-strings
   ( $multipleStringInput as item()+ )  {
     let $firstString := $multipleStringInput[position() = 1]
     let $secondString := $multipleStringInput[position() = 2]
     let $thirdString := $multipleStringInput[position() = 3]
     let $concat :=
                     concat(
                            $firstString, 
                            $secondString, 
                            $thirdString)
     return bs:next-function($concat)
  } ;
```

So my goal is to group this multiple strings into smaller variables by 3 to be able to work with them separatelty and get to them like above with constant [position() = 1], [position() = 2], [positon() = 3] then concat them and pass each to next function OR to somehow change position [1,2,3] -> [4,5,6] in each iteration.

eg:

INPUT: 
'Cat', 'likes', 'fish', 'Dog', 'likes', 'bones'

OUTPUT:
bs:next-function('Catlikesfish')
bs:next-function('Doglikesbones')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `tumbling window` clause https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-windows e.g.

```
for tumbling window $window in ('Cat', 'likes', 'fish', 'Dog', 'likes', 'bones')
start at $s when $s mod 3 = 1
return
  string-join($window)
```

To call your function on each item use the map operator `!`:

```
(for tumbling window $window in ('Cat', 'likes', 'fish', 'Dog', 'likes', 'bones')
start at $s when $s mod 3 = 1
return
  string-join($window)
  )
  ! bs:next-function(.)
```